# LTO3 tape read only on a LTO3 tape driver (write lock unlocked)

Tags: windows-server-2003, tape, read-only, lto-3

I've installed on win2003 a tape drive (IBM 25R0012) with the latest drivers available
 The tape is functioning correctly (according to the "Device Manager"), however when I insert a new tape (i use the MMC for the management of removable storage) this end up in the pool "Unrecognized \ Unknown" and if I try to move on the available media I get: "the storage medium is write protected"

In fact, between the properties of the media here:

Name: 5
 Status: Waiting
 identification
 Type: Unknown (read only)
 Sequence number: 5
 Bar code:

Media pool: Unrecognized \ Unknown
 Online Library: IBM Ultrium-TD3 SCSI Sequential Device
 Unit: Unit 0

Active support: true

Everything I found on the net is based on the fact that the drive is a different generation than tape but in my case I have a reader of the LTO3 and LTO3 tapes.
 only thing is that I'm not sure the tape is IBM and the tapes are HP (C7973A) .. but this is not a problem right?

PS: of course the plastic tab for write protection is in place proper

Comment: Have you already tried to write a free media label on the tape?

Comment: I have exactly the same situation except using LTO2 tapes in an LTO2 drive. The media has been used before with Netbackup (I can read this from the tapes using Quantum xtalk). Xtalk can also read and write to it's hearts content - frustrating. Have you tried using a new tape? I bought the drive on Ebay and it had 8 tapes, so I may just have to buy some new ones...